# Sum over text values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with excel with a column with over 1000 values that looks as follows:

15hrs
12hrs
34hrs
etc..

Can someone please give me a method on how to sum over these values as I have no clue on how to do this..

Comment: Are always the first two characters numbers and rest are letters?

Comment: The sum function doesn't work? =sum(A1:A100)

Comment: Yes @LeNoon and no lordkain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the A1:A3 to be the actual range:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"hrs",""))
```

Comment: +1 didn't know `SUBSTITUTE` worked with arrays as well! Also, you can use `=SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"hrs",""))` which I think works a little faster.

Comment: Sum will only work if you array-enter the formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter).  Otherwise, it gets the value that is on the same row as the cell the formula was entered on.  Sumproduct will convert it to an array without requiring that the formula be array-entered.

Answer (score 1):

Take a copy, replace `hrs` with nothing, then sum the result.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sum over the text values, but you can get what you're looking to do in a different way (if this'll work for you):

1. Select the column and go Replace all `"Hrs"` with blanks `""` - In effect, making your text numbers
2. With the column values still highlighted, go to `Format Cells` and choose the "Custom" format... Change the format to `General"Hrs"`
3. Now you can add the values since they are stored as values, but LOOK like text.

I don't know if this'll work for you, but it should accomplish the task at hand if it does...